# 'BackgroundService' is a namespace but is used like a type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, background-service

I'm creating a background service in .NET 8, but I get the below error

> Error CS0118  'BackgroundService' is a namespace but is used like a type

This was working in .NET 6 version.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled **Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting** but does not seem to work.

Creating new project and facing this issue:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace BackgroundService
{
    public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                if (_logger.IsEnabled(LogLevel.Information))
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
                }
                await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a NameSpace in your code that includes "BackgroundService"? Like "my.company.services.BackgroundService.Service1" or something similar?

Comment: It's kind off hard to debug code we can't see.

Comment: Please add a [mre].

Comment: @GuruStron Added. Its a new project that i'm creating in .Net 8.

Comment: You should generally avoid using names that will cause a name clash in the first but, in this situation, you could just qualify the type name when inheriting that class rather than relying on the `using` import. If two things have the same name then you can ALWAYS qualify one or both to disambiguate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the namespace `BackgroundService` to something else otherwise it shadows the type name:

```
namespace MyApp.BackgroundServices
{
    public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can specify the fully qualified type name (though I would argue that the first option should be preferred):

```
public class Worker : Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.BackgroundService
{
   // ...
}
```